# How to Correct Slang words using python or Nltk?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, error-correction, spelling

I have some text got from web, but people wrote them in short forms, like uni for university, and awsm for awesome etc, but I can guess the lists of those words. But how to correct them with Python? I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
APPOSTOPHES= {"'s": "is", "'re":"are"}    
s= " i luv my iphone, you're awsm apple. DisplayisAwesome, Sooooo happppppy"
words = s.split()
rfrm=[APPOSTOPHES[word] if word in APPOSTOPHES else word for word in words]
rfrm= " ".join(rfrm)
print(rfrm)

i luv my iphone, you're awsm apple. DisplayisAwesome, Sooooo happppppy
```

But it prints the same sentence. It didn't change anything.

Comment: `APPOSTOPHES[word]` isn't going to match any of the items in your list.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few things going on with your code, the first of which being that you're not matching any of your candidate replacements in your `APPOSTOPHES[word]` check.

I broke out the code in very clear chunks and did a minor correction in your `APPOSTROPHES` dictionary -- note the space that is now in the value.  The rest of the description is in code comments:

```
APPOSTOPHES= {"'s": " is", "'re":" are"}    
test_string = " i luv my iphone, you're awsm apple. DisplayisAwesome, Sooooo happppppy"

# split the words based on whitespace
sentence_list = test_string.split()

# make a place where we can build our new sentence
new_sentence = []

# look through each word 
for word in sentence_list:
    # look for each candidate
    for candidate_replacement in APPOSTOPHES:
        # if our candidate is there in the word
        if candidate_replacement in word:
            # replace it 
            word = word.replace(candidate_replacement, APPOSTOPHES[candidate_replacement])

    # and pop it onto a new list 
    new_sentence.append(word)

rfrm = " ".join(new_sentence)
print(rfrm)
# i luv my iphone, you are awsm apple. DisplayisAwesome, Sooooo happppppy
```

edit: As Alexis's comment calls out, the word/contraction replacement will lead to trouble if you try to apply the same pattern for everything.  I went with this approach because your variable name is close to the word "apostrophes" -- and that's what we're changing.  His suggestion to use the nltk tokenize method is a good one; if you're going to be basing your approach on a library, definitely learn its preferred methods.

My answer is meant to get you over your immediate hurdle and show you why you were getting the same sentence string in response.

Comment: This makes this particular substitution, but doing partial-word replacement for this task is a really bad idea. Just think about it... `"u": "you"`

Comment: Sure, but that's something that the asker would find later in his approach.  I looked at your answer and it opens a whole new can of worms.

Comment: You looked at my answer and you think the NLTK api's approach is wrong? Let's hear why.

Comment: I don't expect you to fix all the OP's problems (I certainly don't try to), but the OP's code matches complete words.  *You* introduce a problem by using partial matches, and you say that's fine because it's "something the asker will find later in his approach"? Wow.

Comment: What's "wow" about it?  I'm doing what the OP was attempting to do in his approach.  Do you expect an answer to teach him how to do slang classification?  He wanted to match apostrophes.  My code does that for him.  I purposefully did not match on letters like "u" because obviously.  Mentioning the NLTK API, which you didn't, is not the same as having a comprehensive answer.  The asker is obviously learning Python, so a path of small steps is better than hand-wavey "hey just do it the right way, good luck!"  Also, his code did _not_ match complete words.  Did you even read it?

Comment: I expected an answer that doesn't break the code worse than before, and fail to acknowledge it. (But with your latest edit, you do acknowledge it.) If the OP's code matched partial words, it would of course be fine for you to do the same; but it doesn't-- just try it.

Comment: It's not making it worse.  I did try mine -- it's only catching the "apostrophe" characters that he wanted (output is: "i luv my iphone, you are awsm apple. DisplayisAwesome, Sooooo happppppy").  Anyway, this is kind of without a point as the asker has gone walk about.  I don't know what's going on locally for you, but this is what the asker was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your code didn't replace anything because you match against complete words, but *'re* is written attached to the previous word. If you hack a solution for apostrophes, you'll soon discover that your code also fails for words near punctuation. E.g., `... luv, susan."`

Since you tagged this `nltk`, just use the nltk's tokenizer instead of `split()`:

```
>>> s = " i luv my iphone, you're awsm apple. DisplayisAwesome, Sooooo happppppy"
>>> nltk.word_tokenize(s)
['i', 'luv', 'my', 'iphone', ',', 'you', "'re", 'awsm', 'apple', '.', 'DisplayisAwesome', ',', 'Sooooo', 'happppppy']
```

Now *'re* is a complete token, and your code will work as intended. (It'll also change `John's dog` into `John is dog`, but that's inherent in your approach).

Incidentally, note that contracting *is* and *are* is not "slang". It's used in all sorts of texts.

Comment: Ah, I see. But you removed my demonstration that "It's" can appear in non-slang text :-( By the way, if you changed it to a downvote, could you let me know what's wrong?

Comment: it's safe to delete your comments now

Comment: @alexis hi i know it has been long since this answer was posted, but nltk.wordtokenize(s) yields `['I', 'luv', 'my', '<', '3', 'iphone', '&', 'you', '’', 're', 'awsm', 'apple', '.', 'DisplayIsAwesome']` in nltk 3.2.3. Probably that was an older version's output.

Comment: Look more carefully, your test text contains a directed quote in `you’re`. Use an ascii apostrophe (`you're`) and it's still tokenized as shown in the answer.